# How to set camera permissions for iOS simulator using Appium Execute Mobile Command (ExecuteScript) - C#

Tags: c#, appium, xcuitest

I'm trying to set camera permission via [Execute Mobile Command](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/mobile-command/index.html) using C#

here is my code snippet I tried to set camera permissions for iOS simulator

```
driver.ExecuteScript("mobile:setPermission", new Dictionary<string, string> { { "bundleId", "com.ios.mytestapp" }, { "camera", "yes" }});
```

and getting error as below

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: The 'access' option is expected to be a map
```

I'm not sure how to fix as there are no examples related C#... can anyone tell me what is the right command.

when I try  `xcrun simctl privacy <uidi> grant camera <bundleid>` (terminal) and works fine but  via mobile command, failed to grant camera permissions

Answer (score 0):

I was able to change the permissions like this:

```
driver.execute("mobile: setPermission", {"bundleId": "<ID>", "access":{'camera': 'YES'}});
```

wasn't able to read them yet tho :) This is how I did found this topic :)